# Add css styling to twig template (class found style not applied)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twig

I just want my CSS to apply, not sure where I'm messing up...

Alright so in my base.html.twig I have defined this

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('web/css/main.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% endblock %}
```

The whole path to the main CSS file.

> K:\phpstormproject\symfony\my-project\web\css\main.css

In the CSS file, the class is found when starting to type but the change is not being applied.
Here is a simple change

```
.font-weight-light {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I tried deleting the cache but that doesn't really do the job, does it have anything to do that it's a bootstrap class?

Comment: try to reload your file using version. Like this main.css?v.0

Comment: Inspect with chrome debugger tools...press F2 on your keyboard and on the right side you will see your css properties

Comment: Console says: "

2
main.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: And when i check the file(in console browser) it is indeed empty...

Comment: Hey so i fixed the error but my styles still wont load.